# Using Nutch and Elasticsearch with indexer-elastic-rest

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I've used Nutch and Elasticsearch many times before, however, I believe I was using the default setup to where Nutch used the binary transport method for communicating with Elasticsearch. It was simple and worked out of the box so I've used it alot.

I've been in the process of updating crawl system and it seems now the better option is to use the [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest) REST api library.

However, I'm a bit confused about it...

First how do I install the Jest library to be used with Nutch and Elasticsearch. I know I can download or clone via Github but.. how is it connected?

Do I literally just update the dependencies in the /indexer-elastic-rest *.xml files for Nutch and then just build again with ant?

My first install of Nutch was using the binary zip. I just recently started using the src package so ant/maven is somewhat new to me - which is why this all a bit confusing. All the blogs and articles say to "and then rebuild with ant"...

Second - does the Jest library take care of all Java REST api code or do I have to write Java code now?